# What's the difference between ${foo} and #{bar}?

Tags: groovy

What's the difference between `${foo}` and `#{bar}` in string placeholders?

Answer (score 2):

`#{}` is not a plain groovy construct, it's not evaluated.

```
def foo = 1
def bar = 2

println "${foo} and #{bar}"
```

returns

```
 1 and #{bar}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it got mixed with Ruby and/or Coffeescript's own string interpolation.

Ruby:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = "foo"
=> "foo"
irb(main):002:0> "this is a #{a}"
=> "this is a foo"
```

[Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/):

```
a = "coffee"
alert "i'd love some #{a}"
```

---

Groovy uses `${}` notation and the string needs to be declared using double quotes or triple double quotes:

```
groovy:000> a = "bar"
===> bar
groovy:000> """to the $a"""
===> to the bar
groovy:000> "to the ${a}"
===> to the bar
```

Comment: Or a slashy string, or a dollar-slashy string. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_string_summary_table